# How do I print to the console the even indexed numbers in C#?

Tags: c#

This is what I have so far...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

class Solution 
{
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        string testCaseNumber = Console.ReadLine();
        string string1 = Console.ReadLine();
        string string2 = Console.ReadLine();

        List<char> evenIndex1 = new List<char>();
        List<char> oddIndex1 = new List<char>();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 10000; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                if (i == string1.Length)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    char even = string1[i];
                    evenIndex1.Add(even);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(i == string1.Length)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    char odd = string1[i];
                    oddIndex1.Add(odd);   
                }
            }
        }        
        Console.Write(evenIndex1);
    }
}
```

I also did a ton and I'm still really stumped. I'm a beginner so there is a lot of things I still don't know.

Comment: What's not working with your code?

Comment: it prints out System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Char] instead of the items in the list....

Comment: Try: `Console.Write(string.Join(",", evenIndex1));`     _(using System.Linq;)_

Comment: I would suggest you rebuild your solution with a `StringBuilder` and don't loop until `10000`, loop until `string1.Length`

Comment: You could convert it to a string like this: `evenIndex1 = string.Join(",", evenIndex1.ToArray());`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already an be sure to take a look at [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: string.Join worked!!! But how does it work....Im curious.....

Comment: @Invisiblekat see the link I have appended within my answer for explanation on how it works.

Comment: Thank you Ousmane!! You helped me a lot^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I print to the console the even indexed numbers in C#?

There are so many ways in which you can do it. Here are a few of them:

**replace this:**

```
Console.Write(evenIndex1);
```

**with this:**

```
evenIndex1.ForEach(Console.WriteLine); //requires importing -> using System.Linq;
```

**another way:**

```
foreach(var item in evenIndex1) Console.Write(item + " ");
```

You could also concatenate all the items within the collection using **[String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx)** then print it like this:

```
Console.Write(string.Join(",", evenIndex1));
```

further reading on how the methods used work:

- [**String.Join Method**](https://www.dotnetperls.com/string-join)
- [**List.ForEach Method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", oddIndex1.ToArray()));
```